# Modify App.config permanently C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio, appsettings

OK, so I'm trying to use the `appSettings` element in the `App.Config` file to determine what kind of storage to use.

Here is my **app.config** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="storage" value="memory"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

So I want to change the value of the storage "setting" to "xmlfile", so I wrote this method to change the field following some post I found on the internet:

```
public static void UpdateAppSettings(string keyName, string keyValue)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    doc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

    foreach (XmlElement elem in doc.DocumentElement)
    {
        if (elem.Name == "appSettings")
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in elem.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (node.Attributes[0].Value == keyName)
                {
                    node.Attributes[1].Value = keyValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    doc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
}
```

How ever when I use it, there is no change to the App.Config. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

**P.S.**

Just for reference I'm only using the following simple method to test it:

```
    Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storage"].ToString());
    Console.Read();
    AppConfigFileSettings.UpdateAppSettings("storage", "xmlfile");
    Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storage"].ToString());
    Console.Read();
```

Which just prints out "memory" twice.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you see that behavior is due the configuration being loaded only once and the subsequent accesses to the application configuration settings are coming from memory.

You can use `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")` to refresh the applciation settings section and this way the new value will be loaded into memory.

Comment: wow, nice. I didn't know this was possible. So one can change all the config at runtime.